# Is there a fast way to turn MessageBox into non modal dialog?

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I want to show multiple windows at once.

```cpp
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    Sleep(10);
    MessageBox(NULL, "Some information", NULL, MB_OK);
  }
```

It's showing them one after another, but I want to show them all at one time

(Sorry for my English)

Thanks!

Comment: The reason for this is `MessageBox` is a modal dialog,

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556089/is-there-any-way-to-have-async-messagebox

Comment: `MessageBox(NULL, "Some information", NULL, MB_OK | MB_TASKMODAL);`

Comment: You can create multiple threads (not recommended), are you creating a joke/virus app?

Comment: This may help with the threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617450/how-do-you-create-a-message-box-thread

Comment: Multi threads are working with `MessageBoxA(NULL, "Some text", NULL, MB_ICONERROR);` but not with `MessageBoxA(NULL, "Some text", NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_TOPMOST);` .Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Straight from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox): *"Displays a modal dialog box that contains a system icon, a set of buttons, and a brief application-specific message, such as status or error information. **The message box returns an integer value that indicates which button the user clicked.**"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MessageBox` is a [modal dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dialog-boxes), the function does not return until the dialog has been closed. Multiple `MessageBox`s can only be created if you have multiple threads in your process. `MessageBox` is a special version of `DialogBox`.

You can use `CreateDialog` to create modeless dialogs but you should not show many dialogs to the user at the same time. I would recommend that you create a single dialog with a ListView if you need to display many "events" to the user at the same time.